# Code appearing in my RMarkdown PDF output despite using all code chunk instructions

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr

I'm using R Studio and a RMarkdown file that I output as a PDF using Knitr.

There is some code that appears, even though I have set echo=false and comment=na for my code chunks.

The two code bits that appear in my PDF (and that I would want to hide) are :

1. I see this line over a graphic made with ggplot : **‘geom_smooth()‘ using formula = ’y ~ x’**
2. I see this over all of different *table()* outputs : **# A tibble: 8 x 3**

Is there a way to hide that kind of code from my outputs? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Just to make sure, I also added

`{r echo=FALSE, comment=NA, MESSAGE=FALSE, INCLUDE=FALSE, WARNING=FALSE, ERROR=FALSE, RESULTS="hide"}`

before my chunks, and yet, i'm still seeing these bits.

Comment: The arguments have to be lower cased, not upper cased as you have there.